# Understanding Make in C

Tags: c

I am a seasoned developer in Java and I had learned C in my College days, however I am brushing up my C skill and am following a tutorial from [Here](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex2.html)

I am trying to follow a tutorial on makefile here is what the author says:

```
Does the file ex1 exist already?
No. Ok, is there another file that starts with ex1?
Yes, it's called ex1.c. Do I know how to build .c files?
Yes, I run this command cc ex1.c   -o ex1 to build them.
I shall make you one ex1 by using cc to build it from ex1.c.
```

But I am unable to grasp, what is a  makefile and why is it used? What are the parameters to the same? Also what are CFLAGS? What is CC? I am new to Ubuntu although.

Comment: The [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) would help you. Read chapter 2: *An Introduction to Makefiles*.

Comment: Will follow that :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good explanation would be very long.

Short explanation: makefile is a set of instructions on how to compile / build an executable. It includes all relationships. For example, "executable A needs object files B and C. B is compiled from files X.c X.h Y.c and Y.h; C depends on K.c". Now if someone modifies K.c, you know you need to recompile C but you don't need to recompile B (just link B and C into A at the end).

As projects get more complicated this becomes more important.

As for flags - there are all kinds of ways to control your compiler. Sometimes you will want to change these - say, you want to include more debug, or increase level of optimization; or change the target architecture. All these things are controlled with flags. By setting a variable to contain these flags, you can replace the flags in many commands at the same time.
 You can even change what compiler you want to use - you might have different ones as your source code might contain more than one language (mixtures of C and FORTRAN are still encountered in many numerical analysis libraries, for example.)

`cc` is a C compiler. So is `gcc` (the Gnu C Compiler). Other compilers include `g++` (for C++), `g77` (for FORTRAN77), etc...

All of this means that using a makefile is great for maintaining control and flexibility when compiling large and complex projects.

But really - you need to read up about this properly and not rely on something that was written late at night...

Comment: Thank You, so I take note that this is a "Not to be skipped part".

Comment: @user2822178 - if you want to get good at C, you should not skip this. As soon as you have more than one source file, it quickly becomes necessary. Note that many development environments do much of this work "behind your back", although you can usually do some manual tuning. It you can only learn one thing - pointers or makefiles - then go for pointers. But you sound like you have a bit more capacity than that. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the much much valuable guidance. I am learning C to develop in iOS and I want the basics to be crystal clear :) So I take the advice and work on it. Thanks once again and lots love from Kashmir <3